# Firebase Console does not show my app version in the target filter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented firebase notifications in my app last year and all worked fine, now this year I've been modifying images in my app to bring the visual design up to date and upon testing notifications I've found that my version is not listed in firebase console under cloud messaging.

If I look at the dashboard it shows that version 2.0 exists however when I go into cloud messaging and put in the filter to only target my app version it only shows 1.0 & 1.2 which were versions from last year.

Any ideas on why the filter isn't showing my new version but the dashboard is showing it?

Comment: Please include the code where you believe the error is occurring, as well as your expected output.

Comment: @HS-nebula There is no code, the application should be working as expected as the dashboard is showing my version 2.0 however when trying to implement the filter to only send a notification to my version it is not listed

Comment: I have the same problem. I guess I just takes very long to refresh. Is there anything you found out?

Answer (score 1):

If the version is not shown, then type in the new version in the search box and click Create value like in the screenshot.

[image: firebase_Console]

Comment: Not possible anymore on the new UI. Terrible